# How do I give my Ubuntu machine a domain name on a Windows network?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, domain, samba, git

I want to setup a GIT server on my Ubuntu machine in the office but I want a domain name for it that I can connect to from Windows machines on the same network. I've read about using Samba or adding the machine to Active Directory but I'm a bit lost with both. All machines are on the same a.b.com domain.

I have modified my hosts file on the Ubuntu machine to show the following: 127.0.0.1 ubuntu 127.0.1.1 ubuntu.a.b.com ubuntu 192.168.0.9 ubuntu.a.b.com ubuntu

I have admin credentials to the domain controllers and Active Directory. What can I do to enable other Windows machines to access the Ubuntu machine for something like SSH or a GIT server via a domain name rather than the machines IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a static entry on your DNS server for that machine.  Just add an A record for that machine and the 'subdomain' name you want to give it under Forward Lookup Zones and your appropriate domain name.

Comment: Do I not need to add the machine into Active Directory or anything like that then? Seems pretty simple, will give it a try in the morning!

Comment: this will only work if your local machines have the DNS server as their DNS server. Ubuntu by default uses itself as a DNS server if you check `/etc/resolv.conf` so it wont actually "adopt" the FQDN.

Comment: This solution ended up working fine for me, I just added a DNS record into one of the domain controllers.

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu, you need to first edit your `/etc/hostname` file and set your desired hostname without the domain included. For this example i will use the hostname LINUX and domain UBUNTU.COM.

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/hostname` and set your desired hostname, in this example `LINUX` then write changes.
2. Update your hostname by running `sudo hostname -F /etc/hostname`.
3. Check `/etc/hostname` by running `cat /etc/hostname`.

Your `/etc/hostname` file should now look like this:

```
LINUX
```

Now lets take a look to see if your machine is already looking for your domain name.

- Run `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. If you get a line showing `search UBUNTU.COM` then we can skip this part as your machine is aware of the domain.

if you don't get `search UBUNTU.COM` and you don't see `nameserver <ip of your DNS Server>`

1. Edit your `resolv.conf` file by running  `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`
2. Add `search UBUNTU.COM`.
3. Add `nameserver <ip of DNS Server>` and write changes.
4. Run `sudo resolvconf -u` to update your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.
5. Check your updated `resolv.conf` by running `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and you should now see `search UBUNTU.COM` and `nameserver 192.168.0.15` or whatever your DNS server's IP is as the first thing your Ubuntu machine will search for.

### Now let's update your `/etc/hosts` file

1. Run `sudo nano /etc/hosts`.
2. On the line that has `127.0.1.1 LINUX` change it to `127.0.1.1 LINUX.UBUNTU.COM LINUX` and write changes.
3. Now we run `sudo service networking restart` to refresh changes.

### Lets check to see if changes took effect.

- Check Hostname: `hostname` which should return `LINUX`.
- Check Domain: `hostname -d` which should return `UBUNTU.COM`.
- Check FQDN: `hostname -f` which should return `LINUX.UBUNTU.COM`.
- Check Name Resolution: `nslookup LINUX.UBUNTU.COM` should return results from the DNS server you added in `resolv.conf`. If it cant find it then you may need to give it time to update or manually add an A record in your DNS server for your Ubuntu machine.
- (If above resolved fine) Ping your FQDN! `ping LINUX.UBUNTU.COM` should return ping responses from your IP Address.

Comment: Very informative but the answer above worked for me!